# How to get saved value in select tag in generic UpdateView?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-generic-views

I'm editing a form with a generic UpdateView. When I open the form I'm unable to get the saved value to show up in the select tag, other fields are working properly.

models.py

```
class employee_master(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    for_station = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    contact_no = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email_id = models.EmailField(max_length=200)
    joining_date = models.DateField(max_length=200)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(max_length=200)
    address = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pin_code = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    remarks = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('master:employee-detail')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

forms.py

```
class EmployeeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    city = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=city_master.objects.all())
    state= forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=state_master.objects.all())
    country = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=country_master.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model=employee_master
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets= {
            'name':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'for_station': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'contact_no': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'email_id': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'joining_date': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'date_of_birth': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'address': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control','rows':2, 'cols':10}),
            'country': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'state': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'city': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'pin_code': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'remarks': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control','rows':2, 'cols':10}),
        'active': forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'class': 'form-check-input'}),
    }
```

views.py to create and update, I am using the same form

```
class EmployeeCreate(CreateView):
    model = employee_master
    form_class = EmployeeForm

class EmployeeUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = employee_master
    form_class = EmployeeForm
```

I expect that the country, state and city saved values should appear when I edit.

Comment: How are you populating the dropdown?

Comment: @Sergio Dropdown are populating with queryset used in forms.py                    
     city = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=city_master.objects.all())

Comment: If you're using a model, you could try to use a foreign key in the employee_master model for city, state and country. Like `models.ForeignKey(
        'city_master')`

Comment: Any other alternative instead of using foreign key??

Comment: A foreign key would make more sense for these fields. You might get away with an `IntegerField` - since the default behavior of `ModelChoiceField` is to use the object's primary key as the value. Try `country = models.IntegerField()`